# TypeScript excess properties error with return type annotation but not when implementing an interface

Tags: typescript

I hope that Class B can not be pass like Class C.

The compilation error of Class C is as follows:

Type '{ name: string; some: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Info'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'some' does not exist in type 'Info'.

```
interface Info {
  name: string;
}

interface Person {
  info(): Info;
}

class B implements Person {
    info() {
        return {
            name: "li",
            some: "1",
        };
    }
}

class C {
    info():Info {
        return {
            name: "li",
            some: "1",
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript checks for excess properties only when you use an object literal in a context in which the required type is immediately known, as in class C (because you annotated the return type).  In class B, TypeScript first infers the return type of `info` based on the expression being returned, i.e., `{name: string, some: string}`.  By that point, the excess properties check has already been skipped.  Then TypeScript checks that the inferred type is assignable to the type `Info` specified by the interface, which it is.

Unfortunately, the error message for class C is misleading.  In general, type `{ name: string; some: string; }` *is* assignable to type `Info`; it's only a "fresh" object literal of type `{ name: string; some: string; }` that is not assignable to `Info`.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26386 for the misleading error message.